# Bazaar plugin: List of modified files on pre-commit hook

Tags: bazaar, bazaar-plugins

I want to write a Bazaar plugin that performs some actions one the modified files before they are committed. Things like checking for syntax errors, and warning the commiter if there are still TODO's in the file.

How do I get a list of the modified files in a Bazaar plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using `pre_commit` hook then your hook function will get `tree_delta` as one of argument (see [doc on hook signatures](http://doc.bazaar-vcs.org/latest/en/user-reference/bzr_man.html#hooks)). You need to use `tree_delta` object to access list of added/modified/renamed files.
[Documentation of TreeDelta class is available here](http://starship.python.net/crew/mwh/bzrlibapi/bzrlib.delta.TreeDelta.html).

[Example of pre_commit hook code you can see here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~bialix/%2Bjunk/checkeol/annotate/head%3A/__init__.py).